# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel Stretching Images

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i'm looking to create a carousel using bootstrap. Everything I try with CSS breaks and the image ratio breaks and inherit the size of the carousel.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K29db.png

```
   <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="../../assets/img/test.png">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Example headline.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Sign up today</a></p>
        </div>

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="../../assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../assets/js/holder.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please refer <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290701/maintain-image-aspect-ratio-in-carousel>