# Bootstrap carousel that keeps the image aspect ratio

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a bootstrap carousel on my website.
I want to keep the image aspect ratio when resizing on smaller screens. How to do this?

Here's some code:

```
<!-- Carousel
================================================== -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="img/bg_good_sex2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="verslaafd-aan-porno-goede-seks">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Sex Coach <span class="text-primary"> App
          </span></h1>
          <p>Krijg controle op porno- of seksverslaving</p>
          <p><a href="<?php echo SSL_DOCUMENT_ROOT ?>/register.php" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"><i class="icon-chevron-sign-right"></i> <?php echo START_BTN ?></a></p>
          <p><a href="<?php echo SSL_DOCUMENT_ROOT ?>/survey_me.php" class="btn btn-success btn-primary btn-lg"><i class="icon-edit"></i> <?php echo BTN_SURVEY_ME ?></a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

Thank you,
Fred

Comment: Can you add a simplified version of your carousel that readers might help you.

Comment: Possibly related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290701/maintain-image-aspect-ratio-in-carousel

Comment: @MikeCauser, this solution has a fixed 500px height. I want the whole content (image and text) of the container to be reduced on smaller displays.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following styles to the `<img>`. This will keep the aspect ratio on large browsers.

```
max-width: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Another option is to use `<div>`'s with background images and use `background-size: cover`

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the above answer and many others without luck, but by using chrome development tools, i've come up with this short solution. Hope this works for you as well:

```
/* Carousel image resize */
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img,  .carousel-inner > .item > img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Its important to use the exact code with the same classes as described above