# How do I set max-width for an image in Bootstrap carousel and keep aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 4 alpha6 and I'm looking for a way to set a max-width for images in my carousel, and at the same time keep aspect ratio.

Setting `height: auto;` doesn't seem to work.

Here's my codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqWObN?editors=1100

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290701/maintain-image-aspect-ratio-in-carousel

Answer (score -1):

The max-width property is used to set the maximum width of a given element. "Height:auto" is taken max-height of the div and if you declare max-width, it will take width according to the height,means maintain aspect ratio..

```
.carousel-item img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Can you add a bit of explanation please?

Comment: Anyone has given me minus vote...for what reason?? what a joke!!

Comment: The max-width property is used to set the maximum width of a given element. "Height:auto" is taken max-height of the div and if you declare max-width, it will take width according to the height,means maintain aspect ratio..

Comment: Thanks for responding -- but -- comments are ephemeral; please *edit your question* to include that information.